# Eigenfunctions to a Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I am trying to find the first 5 eigensolutions to a Sturm-Liouville problem;
I have tried the code;
`DEigensystem[{xy''[x] + y'[x] + (xλ^2 - 1/x)y[x], y[0] == 0, 
  y[1] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}, 5]`
but I'm not getting an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the eigenvalues $\lambda$ in the S-L ODE?

Comment: the p is the eigenvalues

Comment: The proper eigenvalue problem should be in the form $Ly(x)=\lambda y(x)$. You have used the eigenvalue (strangely called $p$) on the LHS instead of the RHS. In the documentation of `DEigensystem` it is shown the correct syntax. Also, use `DirichletCondition`.

Comment: OK, then it is better to use $\lambda$ as that is the standard, and now your equation looks like $x^2 y''+x y'+(\lambda x^2 - 1) y =0 $.  But this is not actually in Sturm-Liouville form either. The standard form for SL is $p(x) x''+ p'(x) x' + (q(x)+ \lambda \sigma(x) ) y=0$. Comparing this to the ODE you wrote, it implies that  $p(x)=x^2$ but now $p'=2 x$ and not $x$ as you have there.  But there are ways to convert almost all second order ODEs to make them in standard SL form.  Many examples are at this [page](http://12000.org/my_notes/faq/math/index.htm#x1-190008.10)